# Form filling in my android app on voice command

Tags: android, dialogflow-es, google-assistant-sdk

I am researching ways to implement form filling via voice command given by user inside my application.I have searched two options but no one is seems useful and I am bit confused here.

First I tried with [android voice to speech library integration](https://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-speech-to-text-tutorial/).It gives me text but isn't smart enough to converse with  as google assistance do.

Then second I tried to [integrate google assistance](https://dialogflow.com/docs/integrations/google-assistant) with api.a. It provides the user conversation but it is like adding command to google assistance .It doesn't provide me voice to text data so that I can fill form and do further operation.

Please suggest me ways to implement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You wouldn't use Actions on Google through Dialogflow for your implementation but rather the [Google Assistant SDK](https://developers.google.com/assistant/sdk/) which is meant for devices.

However, in your case it may make sense to use [Dialogflow's Android client](https://github.com/dialogflow/dialogflow-android-client). You would not need to pull all of the Google Assistant's capabilities and the voice interaction would be limited to your own application.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the SDK provided by [Slang Labs](https://slanglabs.in) which allows you to add a custom voice experience inside your app. You can create a "buddy" in their console and configure the kind-of intents/utterances you want to handle. Then integrate its SDK into your app, which takes care of all the voice-related functionality and you can register callbacks for the intents you have configured in the console to handle the app-specific actions.

(disclaimer: I am a co-founder of Slang Labs :-))